# How to send email with commas in the name?

Tags: 8, emails

I am trying to send email of the format: `'Tom Smith, Jr <ts@example.com>'`; but it fails due to the comma in the name.

This closed issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2936032 dealt with handling commas in the site name for handling the From address. It basically added a helper function to wrap the name part in double quotes. But this doesn't work for the To address.

Any suggestions other than simply removing the comma?

Answer (score 2):

`Tom Smith, Jr <ts@example.com>` and `'Tom Smith, Jr <ts@example.com>'` are not valid email addresses, but `"Tom Smith, Jr" <ts@example.com>` is. Drupal doesn't "fix" addresses to make them [RFC 2047](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2047.html) compliant, you need to do that yourself or use a helper module (such as Mime Mail) which will take care of a lot of these little details for you. This is especially important if you want to use non-ASCII characters in your email addresses.

Drupal 8 core provides a `\Drupal\Component\Utility\Mail::formatDisplayName()` method you can use, but it is well-known to do the wrong thing in many cases and has been removed in Drupal 9.2. This is part of the reason the above-mentioned helper modules exist.

Comment: Thanks but adding double quotes as I mentioned, doesn't work.

Comment: Is it possible the failure comes from the mail server? I am using Papercut SMTP as a test mail server. There isn't much for error reporting; any issue is just returned as "can't send". It is hard to imagine that Drupal mail can't handle "last, first" as an email name.